# What does the expression "jocks and jockesses" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I am watching Fraggle Rock Ep303.
In this episode, Red says she's organizing an exhibit on athletic excellence for the annual **Jock and Jockesses** Picnic.
I am wondering the meaning of "jocks and jockesses".
Is it a humorous expression for sports athletes?

Answer (score 10):

The word ‘jock’ has several different possible meanings, but used here, it’s a term for a male athlete. It’s often used in a derogatory manner, implying a lack of intelligence — the typical high-school-drama tv show plotline involves some kind of altercation between the ‘nerds’ and the ‘jocks’ — but not always.

The ‘-ess’ suffix is generally used to show that it’s a female form of the word, as in ‘countess’ and ‘count’. So a ‘jockess’ would be a female athlete, and ‘jockesses’ would be the plural form.

Jockess isn’t a ‘real’ word — and sounds quite silly to native speakers, because we associate the word ‘jock’ with a certain kind of maleness — which could be the source of the humour.

Comment: Would it be fair to say the usage of "jockess" is jock-ular? Ahem. I'll get my coat.

Comment: @PrimeMover that actually took me a while to get :D

Comment: This sounds reasonable, but are you sure that "jocks" isn't the name of one of the creatures on the show? I'm not an expert on it, but it seems plausible.

Comment: @nick012000 it's not.

Comment: Due to the derogatory implication of the word, I wonder if one of the writers was playing off the word jackass, but it's probably just a coincidence that the words sound similar.

Comment: @nick012000 it would be a massive coincidence if it were, or a weird writing decision,